# I like to move it move it

Tags: code-golf

King Julian needs to get through the jungle, but he's feeling lazy. He wants a computer to be able to calculate a route through the jungle for him.

Using STDIN get a map of the jungle for the computer to crack. It will follow the following format:

```
01001E
010110
000P00
1100J1
S00111
```

The way the jungle map works is:

`0` is ground that Julian can move along.

`1` is dense impassable jungle.

`P` is an area with predators in it, that you must avoid at all costs.

`J` is relatively thick jungle. Julian's minions can break through one of these before tiring.

`S` is where Julian starts. It can be anywhere on the map.

`E` is where Julian wants to go; the end of the path. It also can be anywhere on the map, just like any other tile.

Every character is a tile on the map. Line breaks indicate a new row of tiles. If STDIN in your language does not support line breaks, the line break must be replaced by a space to signify a new row.

To move between the tiles, you must output a string using STDOUT containing the following special characters:

`F` - Forward

`B` - Backward

`L` - Rotate Julian left (90 degrees anticlockwise)

`R` - Rotate Julian right (90 degrees clockwise)

`M` - Minions destroy a `J` tile 1 tile forward from Julian, if there is one (`M` just clears out the tile, you still have to move onto it)

A possible output would be:

```
RFFLFRFMFLFRFLFF
```

Which solves the map above.

Notes:

- If your program outputs a solution which hits predators, game over.
- If you hit impassable jungle, you just bounce back to where you were before you ran into dense jungle, facing the same way. (Toward the jungle)
- Julian starts facing upwards. (^ That way ^)
- The output doesn't have to be the fastest solution, `FFF` and `FBFBFBFBFBFFF` are the same. **However, outputting the fastest possible solution gives a -10% byte count bonus.**
- If a map is invalid, STDOUT 'Invalid map.' (That includes if the map is unsolvable)
- A map cannot have rows or columns of different lengths; that makes it invalid.

Your answer should somewhat follow this format:

```
#Language name, *n* bytes

    code

Explanation (optional)
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes  wins.

Comment: Your solution example has Julian walking straight into a predator. Something like RFFLFRFMFLFRFLFF should work instead.

Comment: @Emigna, Oops. I got mixed up between thick jungle and a predator's lair...

Comment: Does a `P` tile really add something different from a `1` tile?  I can't really imagine a plausible solution that treats them any differently.

Comment: @dan1111 The P tile kills Julian when he travels over it. The 1 tile Julian can't pass through, but if Julian hits it he doesn't die, he just bounces back.

Comment: @Tobsta, yes, I understand.  But does that make a difference?  It seems like any successful solution would just avoid 1 and P tiles.

Comment: @dan1111 Yes, it would.

Comment: Do minions have a limit on how many tiles they can destroy?

Comment: @JAtkin no, they don't.

Comment: Do you have more mazes?

Comment: Clarification request: In comments, you said minions don't have a limit on how many tiles they can destroy, but how does that fit with "Julian's minions can break through one `J` before tiring"? I assumed that meant a solution could only use `M` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Groovy, 656 bytes

That was too long...

```groovy
i={println"Invalid map."
System.exit(1)}
m=[]
q=System.in.newReader()
r=q.readLine()
while(r!=''){m<<r
r=q.readLine()}
o=m[0].size()
m.each{if(it.size()!=o)i()}
f=[0]*4
m.eachWithIndex{l,n->s=l.indexOf('S')
e=l.indexOf('E')
if(s!=-1){f[0]=s;f[1]=n}
if(e!=-1){f[2]=e;f[3]=n}}
v=[]
t={x,y,d->if(d.contains([x,y])|y>=m.size()|x>=o|x<0|y<0)return
a=m[y][x]
def p=d+[[x,y]]
if(a=='E')v=p
if(a=='J'|a=='0'|a=='S'){t(x-1,y,p)
t(x+1,y,p)
t(x,y+1,p)
t(x,y-1,p)}}
t(f[0],f[1],[])
if(!v)i()
o=0
p=''
v.inject{t,s->
c=m[s[1]][s[0]]
k=[t[0]-s[0],t[1]-s[1]]
z=[[0,1]:0,[1,0]:1,[0,-1]:2,[-1,0]:3][k]
p+=((((o-z)==0)?'':(z>0?'R':'L'))+(c=='J'?'M':'')+'F')
o=z
s}
println p
```

Output for the maze:

```
RFFLFRFMFLFRFLFF
```

Ungolfed:

```groovy
invalid = {
    println "Invalid map."
    System.exit(1)
}
map = """01001E
010110
000P00
1110J1
S00111""".split('\n')

//map = [""]// TODO remove this, this is type checking only
//map.remove(0)
//reader = System.in.newReader()
//line = reader.readLine()
//while (line != '') {
//    map << line.replace('P','1')
//    line = reader.readLine()
//}

size = map[0].size()
map.each {if(it.size() != size) invalid()}

startAndEnd = [0,0,0,0]
map.eachWithIndex {it, idx -> s=it.indexOf('S');e=it.indexOf('E');
    if(s!=-1){ startAndEnd[0]=s; startAndEnd[1]=idx}
    if(e!=-1){ startAndEnd[2]=e; startAndEnd[3]=idx}}

def validPath = []

testMove = {x, y, visited ->// visited is an array of x y pairs that we have already visited in this tree
    if (visited.contains([x,y]) || y>=map.size() || x>=size || x<0 || y<0)
        return;

    def valueAtPos = map[y][x]
    def newPath = visited + [[x,y]]

    if (valueAtPos == 'E') validPath = newPath
    if ((valueAtPos == 'J' || valueAtPos == '0' || valueAtPos == 'S') && !validPath) {
        testMove(x-1, y, newPath)
        testMove(x+1, y, newPath)
        testMove(x, y+1, newPath)
        testMove(x, y-1, newPath)
    }
}
if (!validPath) invalid()
testMove(startAndEnd[0],startAndEnd[1], [])

println validPath

orintation = 0
path = ''
validPath.inject {first, second ->
    def chr = map[second[1]][second[0]]
    def sub = [first[0]-second[0],first[1]-second[1]]
    println "acc:$first, second:$second"
    def newOrin = [[0,1]:0, [1,0]:1, [0,-1]:2, [-1,0]:3][sub]
    path += ((((orintation - newOrin)==0)?'':(newOrin>0?'R':'L')) + (chr=='J'?'M':'') + 'F')
    orintation = newOrin
    second
}
println "path: $path"
```

I will try this again in python soon to see if I can shorten it further.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 273 bytes

```py
E=enumerate
def f(b):
 d={(x,y):v for x,r in E(b)for y,v in E(r)}
 q=[(i,[])for i in d if'S'==d[i]]
 for(x,y),p in q:
  if'E'==d[(x,y)]:return p
  for X,Y in[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]:
   if d.get(t:=(x+X,y+Y))in['0','J','E']and t not in p:q+=[(t,p+['M']*(d[t]=='J')+[t])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVFNawMhED3XXyG5qFkTNLmUBY97WWhZyCVhKyVBtxVSd@OakKX0t6fjph@HpoLOzHtvnuJ0Q3xt/fK@C5dLoaw/vtmwjRYZ2@CG7liOsFHv9MwHlp9w0wZ85gE7jwsgUznw07UM7APhg6qp47UeKZcIg11DVkQpUzutUbIY3XiX2AP4J0ExCkZC58HGY/C4AyrZrPkGpDUVXDIO5ywFyQWcsxR08gATbOYvNtKYK3rO1nzINoxBHxGEkxJ2QfTWGxyxb2O6u8sPGTw38i6ryQPRU2rqqJUCMcsgY/rSS6zwZDIRUghZIAhSCiSEqIRAkIpSohVQUoIIoX5xlQP1vcZUpFUguSrLMhUJrQCvqkqipO@X/zfK1Dg6CPmnMY0pts@7dhsM7WFad1@fV9dTp3@G0Lh9tIE@tt5y3M/7bu8iJU@eMKYR6oLzkTb010gyxm7Ai9vwEuDLJw)